# Put the error message above or below, not next to the editor

Tags: feature-request, error-message

The following screenshot is my focus of visual attention when I write an answer. Note that the sidebar is not included there: People often don't look at the sidebar. They "grey out" anything that's not related to what they're currently doing, which is writing a post, and then clicking the submit button.

> [image]

Where's the "error above", I think. Ah, it's there, overlaying the sidebar. I literally had to look for a couple of seconds before I found the message. It's not really "above", it's rather "on the side".

> [image]

Can we please **put the error message to some place where it can be seen**? The old messages used to pop up right below the question body, where my "region of interest" is, so to speak. Here's the (big fat) button I want to click, and here's the editor I'm focusing on—not the sidebar.

> [image]